# What's the best messaging plugin for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, messaging

I need some standard messaging functionality in my app (i.e. messages received, messages sent, read/unread, trash, etc.)

I've found a few promising leads - acts_as_messageable, has_messages, ActiveMessaging. I'm leaning toward has_messages.

Any experience using these plugins? What's the best choice here?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do you should seriously considering writing this yourself, especially if it's one of your main features.  I took a look at all the plugins you mentioned and found that each one wasn't quite what I wanted.

That said `acts_as_messageable` is great if it does what you want.

Also, `ActiveMessaging` is for message queues, not for people sending each other messages from within your application.